# replace singleton instance in a running roboguice application

Tags: android, dependency-injection, guice, robotium, roboguice

I have an android application using roboguice as a dependency injection framework. There are several singleton services defined, which are used in the application as well in activities. My problem is that we have a robotium test, which testing the workflow in an ActivityInstrumentation2Testcase. The Test should use mocks instead of the the real instance. Unfortunately we couldn't find a possibility to change the reference, because the application is running. Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Until now we didn't find any solution. We created a wrapper for the instances and replaced the inserted delegates. :(